# What does a big F before a function means?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, notation

So I have a homework with this non-homogeneous ODE to solve:

$y'' + y = F \cos (2t)$

My question is simple, what does that $F$ before $\cos(2t)$ means?

The $F$ hasn't been previously addressed in the problem, so I guess it must have some obvious meaning.

Comment: Maybe a constant ??

Comment: You have a **f**orce that is oscillating with amplitude $F$. It is just a constant here.

Comment: Maybe that's it. The question is in fact about a spring damper system.